# Output Woocommerce Product Attributes to Archive Pages and Style with CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I am trying to output product attributes to archive pages. I have successfully output them using the code below but am unable to style them individually.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_display_post_meta', 9 );
function custom_display_post_meta() {
    global $product;
    $attr = array('pa_pg', 'pa_vg', 'pa_nc');
    foreach ( $attr as $attribute ) {
        $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        echo '<div class="new-product-meta">';
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

I should need to wrap a separate class names in `<div>` around each one these, like '`pa_pg`', '`pa_vg`', '`pa_nc`'.

For instance I get 3 `<div>` with the same class names.

Any help on this please?

Comment: Do you have classes for that already? Why don't you use the `$attribute` variable as the class name too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply changing

```
echo '<div class="new-product-meta">';
```

to

```
echo '<div class="new-product-meta '.$attribute.'">';
```

has given me the result i needed. i should have specified i was using woocommerce 2.6.4. also, someone edited part of the original question so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, Just tested my code and it works perfectly on WooCommerce  version 2.6+

Answer (score 0):

First, in WooCommerce 3+ WC_Product properties can't be accessed directly. So I have make your code compatible.

It's very easy to add the attribute taxonomy slug to each  class:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_display_post_meta', 9 );
function custom_display_post_meta() {
    global $product;

    // Get the Product ID - WC 3+ compatibility
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    $product_attributes = array('pa_pg', 'pa_vg', 'pa_nc');

    foreach ( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ) {
        $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

        // => HERE we add the taxonomy name to the <div> class
        echo '<div class="new-product-meta '.$taxonomy.'">';
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $taxonomy, $values );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works